# Can I make Lua-only games?

Tags: lua, game-development

Hey so I was thinking about learning Lua and this question struck to me, that can I program a game which only has Lua code no C++,C, Or side-libraries of C, C++?

Comment: With bare Lua you have no graphics/audio/mouse/joystick/video/touch e.t.c. e.t.c. So you can only make textbased games. But thats games too. On other hand LÖVE (love2d) has support for that but you can make a graphical user interface for your OS. Love2d is a good start because it supports the most operating systems. You can make easily a game for mobile devices - smile

Answer (score 3):

Lua is an embedded scripting language. Like most scripting languages, it runs inside of some application that actually executes what the language says for it to do. So if you want to get technical, it is impossible to run Lua without first running something involving "C", because that "something" is what makes Lua code possible to execute at all.

Because Lua is an embedded scripting language, what you can do with it is ultimately defined by the environment into which it is embedded. `lua.exe` is one embedded environment, but there are others.

So this question is probably intended to be this: Can I make a game in Lua written against the `lua.exe` environment, without adding supplemental, non-Lua modules?

Sure: so long as that game works within the limitations of the text console that `lua.exe` executes within. The standard Lua environment provides access to all of the Lua standard library, but that library is actually quite tiny. The only IO it provides is access to standard in, standard out, standard error, and files.

That's it.

You can make a text adventure game with that. With some knowledge of how to control the text console more directly (which is platform-specific), you can use the console to display ASCII-art graphics. So you could make an old-school Rogue-like, so long as timing isn't a factor, since the Lua standard library has no mechanism for doing that.

Yes, you can make a game of some kind. But the kinds of games you can make with it are probably not what you're thinking of when you said "game". The Lua standard library offers nothing that would allow you to do audio of any kind or anything visual except for sending text to standard out.

Because Lua standard library is intended for any application that needs to embed Lua, it is quite tiny, providing a small baseline of functionality and nothing more. It isn't intended for you to create graphics-intensive applications.

For that, you would need to explore a Lua environment that is designed for that, which provides functionality specific to those needs.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, there are many games made only in Lua and others where you can program mods or servers inside them with Lua only like Roblox or FiveM. If you want to make an entire game using only Lua scripts, you can try using a proper engine for this as for example [GameGuru](https://www.game-guru.com/)

You can also try some Lua libraries made to program games like [Love2D](http://love2d.org/) and [CoronaSDK](https://coronalabs.com/)

Comment: I like gideros mobile.